# How to get connect a JTable to sqlite pro 2009 encrypted password protected database table(sqlite3.db3)

Tags: java, sqlite

I have Created a Sqlite3 databse by using sqlite pro 2009 management studio.which creates a encrypted(Password protected) database and in it i have created a table.I want connect this database table to a jtable.please see the following code.The Following code giving error.

```
        import java.sql.*;
        import javax.swing.*;

        public class javaconnect {

              Connection conn=null;
              public static Connection connecrDb(){

           try{

               Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
               Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\ME\\Desktop\\MY PROJECTS\\final\\sqlitepassword\\okok.db3;Version=3;Password='priya12'");

               return conn;
             }catch ( Exception e){
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                       return null;

              }


       }

      }
```

and Calling this as follows

```
        public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
                     Statement stm=null;
                     Connection conn=null;
                     ResultSet rs=null;
                     PreparedStatement pst=null;

        public NewJFrame() {

                   initComponents();
                   Update_table();

                 }
        public void Update_table() {

             try{
                  conn=javaconnect.connecrDb();
                  String sql="SELECT * FROM ok";
                  pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                  rs=pst.executeQuery();
                  okTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                 }
                  catch( Exception e){
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

                }

           }
```

Comment: Note that randomly formatting/indenting your code makes it hard to read, and this will harm your chances of getting decent help. You also may want to clarify your question further.

Comment: Sorry i have edited the code.please go through it.